# jQuery select only one child in multi-level list

Tags: jquery, selector, children

I've searched and cannot seem to find a way to get only one child when there are several ul/li lists. I need to select only the first child of "Sally" but using "first" or "nth" children give me that child from all of the lists. I've tried using eq() and that didn't work either. Here is the nth code I have with the jQuery below it.

```
<div id="content2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
            <p>Some More Text</p>
            <div>Random Div</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Bob</li>
                <li>Sally
                    <ul>
                        <li>Car</li>
                        <li>Boat</li>
                        <li>Bike
                            <ul>
                                <li>Red</li>
                                <li>Green</li>
                                <li>Blue</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Larry</li>
                <li>Mo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#content2 ul li:nth-child(1)").append("<span> - 1st of Sally </span>");
```

Comment: 'The first child of `Sally`...', do you mean the first list item 'Car'? Or the direct child of `Sally` which is the whole other list? `ul`?

Comment: I meant to get first list item 'Car' which is accomplished by both of the answers below, so that's cool.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#content2 ul:eq(1) li:eq(0)")` would match the first `li` in the second `ul`, which in your html would match Sally's first child, "Car".

Pretty fragile, though, as would any match based on element order.  I'd suggest adding explicit classnames to elements you plan to modify, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content2 div > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1)").append("<span> - 1st of Sally </span>");
```

This isnt pretty but would do the job.  If you do not list `div` in the beginning, red would also be selected, since `ul > li > ul > li` also applies to red.